# IntelliJ project files suddenly broken

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, ide, corrupt

I've been working on a project in IntelliJ IDEA for about two months now. Today, when I fired up the IDE, which would usually open project straight up, IntelliJ took unusually long time to load, and when it did open the project, the main .java file displayed a long line of spaces and nothing else, instead of the code that was there before. The .iml file, the only other thing in the project, was fine. An error message was on the top:

"This document contains very long lines. Soft wraps were forcibly enabled to improve editor performance."

Trying to edit the document results in the entire program freezing and becoming unresponsive. What the hell happened? It was fine one day and then just did this, how do I get my project back and how do I prevent this?

Comment: You can always check the `local history` to see if there were any changes made

Comment: Any chance you ran a command that removed all your carriage returns? What OS are you on? Also, assuming you are not using source control, is this correct?

Comment: Win 8.1. I have no idea what carriage returns are, I'm just trying to write a simple synchronization GUI app here. "View" -> "Recent Changes" don't give anything interesting, just that the project and the file were created 6 days ago.

Comment: Well, isn't that suspicious? You were working on the project for about two months, but "recent changes" says that the project was created 6 days ago?

Comment: Also, by `local history` I meant the option that you get by right-clicking on your source file in the project explorer. `Right click on file > Local History > Show History`.

Comment: Yeah, that "two month ago" was misleading; I just have been working on this particular thing that long. I did indeed create the "project"(as in the bundle if files that IntelliJ works with) six days ago because the old project got screwed up in a similar fashion, so I created a new one and copied the code over, so nothing suspicious there.

Comment: Tried that, the IDE appears to have frozen, but it has been doing that ever since this dreadful business started, so let's see if it unfreezes. I can see some of the history already, and there is a suspicious external change today at 12:11, which is when I was working on the file while in a bus.

Comment: Alright, the original code appears to be there, but the IDE is running ungodly slow.

Comment: OK, reverted the change, whatever it was, and it seems to be working, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved in the comments below the question; thought I might as well post a dummy answer and mark this as resolved.

EDIT: Solution written out.

1. Right click on file > Local History > Show History
2. Find any suspicious changes in the list on the left. Be especially on lookout for "External changes", as those can indicate crashes and sudden power-outs. Alternatively, look for times when you remember your computer crashed or power went out while IntelliJ was open.
3. Revert the changes(curved purple arrow in the upper left corner). Restart the IDE if it's going slow. Everything should work properly now.

Comment: Please improve this by specifying the solution

Comment: I tried the same approach. Code is changing back to as it was before reverting after 2 minutes. I am not even able to change any code in that file.